# VB.Net Update Item Quantity Values getting concatenated instead of getting added in the previuos value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

i am using stored procedure in order to update the stocks item quantity. all the code seems quite ok but dont know why it is not working the it should work. I actually want to update the value of purchased item (Pur_Quantity) in the stocks table referred as masterDetials in the project, but the quantity is not getting updated it is just puting the current value next to the previous value i.e. lets say previous item stock is 52 and i made a new purchase of 8 quantity so the item qunatity should be 60 but its showing me 528 instead of 60.
Can anybody tell me why it is happening and how can it get fixed? 
its a simple question i know but i am new to programing so sorry if it seems silly.
here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdatePurchaseStockQuantity]
(@S_No int,
@Bill_No int,
@Pur_Date datetime,
@Ven_Name NVARCHAR (50),
@ItemName NVARCHAR (150),
@Quantity NVARCHAR (50),
@Unit_Price NVARCHAR (50),
@Total_Price NVARCHAR (50),
@Sub_Total NVARCHAR (50),
@Discount NVARCHAR (50),
@Grand_Total NVARCHAR (50),
@Paid NVARCHAR (50),
@Balance NVARCHAR (50),
@Remarks NVARCHAR (250),
@Pur_Quantity NVARCHAR (50)
)

AS

BEGIN

    INSERT Into Purchase_Cart(S_No, Bill_no, Pur_Date, Ven_Name, ItemName, Quantity, Total_Price, Unit_Price, Discount, Sub_Total, Grand_Total, Paid, Balance, Remarks)
    VALUES (@S_No, @Bill_No, @Pur_Date, @Ven_Name, @ItemName, @Quantity, @Total_Price, @Unit_Price, @Discount, @Sub_Total, @Grand_Total, @Paid, @Balance, @Remarks)


    UPDATE  MasterDetails
    SET     Pur_Quantity = (Pur_Quantity + @Quantity)
    WHERE   ItemName = @ItemName
END
```

here is vb code:

```
 conn.Open()

                For x As Integer = 0 To CartDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1

                    Dim SNo As Integer = CartDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
                    Dim ItemName As String = CartDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
                    Dim Qunatity As String = CartDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
                    Dim UnitPrice As String = CartDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
                    Dim TotalPrice As String = CartDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_MDAndPurchaseCartAddNewRecord", conn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_No", SNo)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_No", BillNoTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pur_Date", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ven_Name", VendorNameComboBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", ItemName)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Qunatity)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit_Price", UnitPrice)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", TotalPrice)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub_Total", TotalPriceTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", DiscountTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grand_Total", GrandTotalTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", PaidTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", BalanceTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", RemarksTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pur_Quantity", Qunatity)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cmd.Dispose()
```

Comment: Your columns need to have appropriate data types. You're using strings for a quantity. When you add 2 strings they just get concatenated which is what you're seeing. A lot of these parameter types should be changed.

Comment: Yeah i got your point this was the reason actually. Got it fixed. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert before using it

```
UPDATE  MasterDetails
SET     Pur_Quantity = (try_convert(int,Pur_Quantity) + try_conver(int,@Quantity))
WHERE   ItemName = @ItemName
```

you can use normal convert, if there is a conversion error then whole update will fail.. to avoid that you can use try_convert which will update null if there is an error in conversion

Answer (score 1):

That's the way string concatenation works:

[MSDN String Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

To add numerical values, you must use numeric data types (not NVARCHAR). If you can not use numeric data types, you can change the sql to something like this:

```
UPDATE  MasterDetails
SET     Pur_Quantity = (CAST(Pur_Quantity As INT) + CAST(@Quantity As INT))
WHERE   ItemName = @ItemName
```

Comment: that's the workaround I'd try - databases exist with numeric quantities expressed as strings - is it always practical to modify?

Comment: That's Great.. Cheers Mate!!